# why isn't the tkinter root background set to a BMP image when using Label and .place()?

Tags: python, image, background, tkinter

As suggested by several SO posts, I created a `Label` to `.place()` a `BMP` picture as background for my window. Unfortunately it does not work as the picture does not appear.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
# generic background
root.tk_setPalette(background='black', foreground='white')
# the background I want to have (but it does not appear)
background_image = tk.PhotoImage("background.bmp")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
# a label with a long text which will be shortened afterwards
mylabel = tk.Label(root, text="a long text", font=("Arial", 30))
mylabel.grid(column=0, row=0)
# the text is shortened to make sure the background adapts
mylabel.configure(text="short")

root.mainloop()
```

`background.bmp` above is the same size as the window (200x200):

[image]

When running the code I get:

[image]

instead of (minus the frames)

[image]

I added in my code a change in the text displayed in the Label to make sure the background adapts (= if the text changes the original background is restored underneath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help(Tk.PhotoImage)`:

> Widget which can display colored images in GIF, PPM/PGM format.

So, you need to save your image as a GIF or Portable Bit Map (PPM/PGM).

Next, I think you're mixing up `PIL`'s `ImageTk.PhotoImage` class with `Tkinter`'s built-in `tk.PhotoImage` class. The `tk.PhotoImage` class needs a `name` argument assigned in its constructor:

```
 |  __init__(self, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw)
 |      Create an image with NAME.
 |      
 |      Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette,
 |      width.
```

So you just need to specify the file, like this:

```
background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
```

However, you'll run into another issue later, because you'll find that the `Label` widget has a non-transparent background color, so it won't display like in your expected output. You can overcome this by using the `Canvas` widget to hold the background and its `create_text()` method to make text on the background.

EDIT: Here's a simple example of using a `Canvas` to make a background, which will preserve the transparency of text:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

bg = PhotoImage(file='background.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg)

canvas.create_text(50, 50, text='Short')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - I was indeed mixing the classes together. Your comment about the non-transparent background of `Label` is a show stopper. I do not have any solution for that, the part you are probably referring to was just a test in my code to make sure that when a shorter text is displayed in the widget, what is left from the longer text is correctly replaced by the background. The `Canvas` solution is not very practical as I rely a lot on some features of `Label` (particularly `.grid()`). What a let-down :)

Comment: It's still do-able, it'll just require some re-writes. You can measure the size in pixels of your font, then make a variable that increments that amount to place text with `create_text()`

Comment: yes, I was actually drawing that as we speak. I will see. Anyway this is a good idea and the soltion since `Label` does not support transparency. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Just as another suggestion, you can use `itemconfig()` on the canvas to update the text. Just assign the `create_text()` to a variable or give it a `tag`. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method